# sql adding specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle  containing fields

> id,location,stock,rate

```
select decode(grouping(id),1,'Total',id) id,loction,
sum(stock) stock,avg(rate) rate from product
group by rollup(id),location
```

I have got

```
ID    Location      stock         rate
------------------------------------------
A          xx          2             10
A          xy          5             20
Total                  7             10

B          SD          3             4
B          RT          6             10
Total                  9             7


C          FG          12            12
C          GH          20            18
Total                  32            15

**Now I want a row of Total rows where sum of stock and 
sum of rate is shown.**

My desired output is


ID    Location      stock         rate
------------------------------------------
A          xx          2             10
A          xy          5             20
Total                  7             10

B          SD          3             4
B          RT          6             10
Total                  9             7


C          FG          12            12
C          GH          20            18
Total                  32            15
Grand Total            48            32
```

Note : Rate is not average but sum of average rate of total rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION` to append the total:

```
select decode(grouping(id),1,'Total',id) id,loction,
sum(stock) stock,avg(rate) rate from product
group by rollup(id),location 
UNION
select 'Grand Total','',sum(stock) stock,sum(rate) rate 
from product
```

If you weren't mixing different aggregates you could get a grand total with `ROLLUP` or with grouping sets, but I don't think you can get a `SUM()` grand total with `AVG()` subtotals.

Comment: yes it will solve my problem ,but Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

```
select decode(grouping(id),1,'Total',id) id,loction,
sum(stock) stock,avg(rate) rate from product
group by rollup(id),location 
union
select sum(stock), sum(rate) from
(
select decode(grouping(id),1,'Total',id) id,loction,
sum(stock) stock,avg(rate) rate from product
group by rollup(id),location 
) where id='Total' group by id;
```

Comment: But it will give the last line only.I want full output as per my question.

Comment: But Grand Total value equals  to sum of Total values in your question

Comment: yes ,  I want out put all the rows,total and grand total value through one sql.

Comment: then my answer true, have you checked my query? is it works in PL/SQL editor (like TOAD for Oracle, or SQLDeveloper)?

Comment: sorry,your sql is right.But it will output only a single row based on the select sum(stock), sum(rate) from
(......) where id='Total' group by id; It is not my out put I have checked it in oracle sqlplus or developer.

Comment: oh, @rishi, I just understand what you need exactly. You may UNION your select query with my select query. I have just updated.

Comment: yes @Farid Imranov your sql is right what i want ,it is also suggested by Goat Co. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `rollup` on all columns will produce the grand total:

```
select (case when grouping(id) = 1 then 'Total' else id end) as id, loction,
       sum(stock) stock,avg(rate) rate
from product
group by rollup(id, location)
```

However, you do not want the rollup on `location`.  So you can filter that out with a `having` clause:

```
select (case when grouping(id) = 1 then 'Total' else id end) as id, loction,
       sum(stock) stock, avg(rate) rate
from product
group by rollup(id, location)
having not (grouping(product.location) = 1 and grouping(product.id) = 0);
```

Comment: `ROLLUP` seems to preserve the aggregate type, so the Grand Total would be the `AVG()` of all `rate` values, not the `SUM()` of the `AVG()` that he's after.  My interpretation of the question was that OP wanted the sum of the subtotal averages, as a grand total, which I'm not sure how you'd go about that in oracle.

Comment: @GoatCO . . . The data example suggests the average rather than the sum, based on two of the three groups.

Comment: The grand total (32) seems to be a sum of the subtotals, which are averages of their groups (save for the first group).

Comment: yes I want grand total rate sum of average rate of total rows achieved from rollup function.